# C pointer arithmetic palindrome

Tags: c

I'm a java student who's currently learning about pointers and C.
I tried to make a simple palindrome tester in C using a single array and pointer arithmetic.
I got it to work without a loop (example for an array of size 10 :*(test) == *(test+9) was true.
Having trouble with my loop. School me!

```
  #include<stdio.h>    

//function declaration
//int palindrome(int *test);

int main() 
{
    int output;
    int numArray[10] = {0,2,3,4,1,1,4,3,2,0};
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &numArray[0];
    output = palindrome(ptr);
    printf("%d", output);
}


//function determine if string is a palindrome
int palindrome(int *test) {    
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= (sizeof(test) / 2); i++) {    
        if (*(test + i) == *(test + (sizeof(test) - i)))    
            return 1;
        else 
            return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(test)` is not going to give you to good result, you should pass an other variable with the length of your array

Comment: `sizeof(test)` is wrong.

Comment: Print `sizeof(test)` in `palindrome()` and see what it shows and go from there.

Comment: In addition to `sizeof()`, your first loop iteration will always return a value rather than checking the entire string.

Comment: Ok. So make an int variable in main with the value sizeof(numArray) ?

Comment: Why did you comment your function declaration?

Comment: That's one way. Or since your `numArray` is hardcoded to size 10, just pass in `10` as another parameter to `palindrome`

Comment: `*(test + (sizeof(test) - i)` is wrong too. Let's assume you've fixed the sizeof(test) problem and you're actually using the value `10` there. Then the first time through your loop, `i` is `0` and you're accessing `*(test+10)` which is one off the end of your array

Answer (score 0):

Why do you copy your pointer in another variable?

```
int *ptr;
ptr = &numArray[0];
```

Just send it to you function:

```
palindrome(numArray);
```

And `sizeof(test)` give you the memory size of a pointer, it's not what you want. You have to give the size in parameter of your function.

```
int palindrome(int *test, int size){
...
}
```

Finally your code must look like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int palindrome(int *test, int size);

int main() 
{
    int output;
    int numArray[10] = {0,2,3,4,1,1,4,3,2,0};
    output = palindrome(numArray, 10);
    printf("%d", output);
}


//function determine if string is a palindrome
int palindrome(int *test, int size) {    
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) {    
        if (*(test + i) != *(test + (size - 1) - i))
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Actually, `sizeof(test)` gives you the size of a pointer, *not* an `int`

Comment: No. See my comment to your question

Comment: @user3102978 your logic was, but not the result :)

Comment: @Ludovic, "Finally your code must look like this:". I hope not. You have mismatched parens in the `for` statement, the `if` statement, and it still only checks the first/last element of the array

Answer (score 0):

The Name of the array will itself acts as a pointer to an first element of the array, if you loose the pointer then there is no means for you to access the element of the array and hence you can send just the name of the array as a parameter to the function.

In the palindrome function:

you have used sizeof(test)/2. what happens is the address gets divided which is meaningless and hence you should not use that to calculate the mid element.

sizeof the pointer will be the same irrespective of the type of address that gets stored.

Comment: " address gets divided which is meaningless". no, that's not what happens. Sizeof(test) returns the size of the pointer, and that's nothing to do with an address

Comment: "if you loose the pointer then there is no means for you to access the element of the array and hence  " this doesn't make any sense and has nothing to do with the problems in the OP's code

Comment: I just started learning pointers very recently. also, I am a crappy programmer. Thanks a lot for the help. Stack overflow is really special that I got replies 10 seconds after posting!

Comment: k i agree what you are saying for the first comment. but you dont get anything in return by doing so. not useful i mean to say... @Paul

Comment: OK but in that case that's what you should actually say. I think this answer confuses more than it helps.